# How do I make this function correctly asyncronous?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to get F# async working, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Here's my sorta syncronous code that runs:

```
open System.Net
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open System.Threading.Tasks

[<DataContract>]
type Person = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "name")>]
    Name : string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "phone")>]
    Phone : int
}

let url = "http://localhost:5000/app/plugins/anon/CCure"
let js  = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Person>)

let main x =
   let client = new WebClient()
   let url = url + "/" + x
   let reader = client.OpenRead(url)
   let person = js.ReadObject(reader) :?> Person

   printfn "Name: %s, Phone number: %d" person.Name person.Phone

printfn "starting x"
let x = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> main "x")
printfn "starting y"
let y = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> main "y")
Task.WaitAll(x, y)
```

I was thinking that to run it asyncronously this would work, but it doesn't:

```
open System.Net
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open System.Threading.Tasks

[<DataContract>]
type Person = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "name")>]
    Name : string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "phone")>]
    Phone : int
}

let url = "http://localhost:5000/app/plugins/anon/CCure"
let js  = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Person>)

let main x = async {
   let client = new WebClient()
   let url = url + "/" + x
   let! reader = client.OpenReadAsync(url)
   let person = js.ReadObject(reader) :?> Person

   printfn "Name: %s, Phone number: %d" person.Name person.Phone }

printfn "starting x"
let x = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> main "x")
printfn "starting y"
let y = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> main "y")
Task.WaitAll(x, y)
```

> $ fsharpc -r System.Runtime.Serialization foo.fs && ./foo.exe F#
>   Compiler for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition) Freely distributed under the
>   Apache 2.0 Open Source License
>
> /home/frew/code/foo.fs(19,18): error FS0001: This expression was
>   expected to have type
>       Async<'a>     but here has type
>       unit
>
> /home/frew/code/foo.fs(20,17): error FS0041: A unique overload for
>   method 'ReadObject' could not be determined based on type information
>   prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.
>   Candidates: XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(reader:
>   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader) : obj,
>   XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(reader: System.Xml.XmlReader) : obj,
>   XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(stream: System.IO.Stream) : obj
>
> /home/frew/code/foo.fs(20,17): error FS0008: This runtime coercion or
>   type test from type
>       'a      to 
>       Person     involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on
>   some types. Further type annotations are needed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess is the `printfn` statement in the main async block. Perhaps adding `person` as the return would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenReadAsync` is part of the .NET BCL and therefore wasn't designed with F# async in mind. You'll notice it returns `unit`, rather than `Async<Stream>`, so it won't work with let!.

The API is designed to be used with events (i.e. you have to wire up `client.OpenReadCompleted`).

You have a couple of options here.

1. There are some nice helper methods in `FSharp.Core` that can help
   you to convert the API into a more F# friendly one (see
   `Async.AwaitEvent`).
2. Use `AsyncDownloadString`, an extension method for WebClient that can be found in `Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions`. This is easier so I've done it below although it does mean holding the whole stream in memory as a string so if you have a huge amount of Json this may not be the best idea.

It's also more idiomatic F# to use async instead of tasks for running things in parallel.

```
open System.Net
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions
open System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

[<DataContract>]
type Person = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "name")>]
    Name : string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "phone")>]
    Phone : int
}

let url = "http://localhost:5000/app/plugins/anon/CCure"
let js  = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Person>)


let main x = async {
   printfn "Starting %s" x
   let client = new WebClient()
   let url = url + "/" + x
   let! json = client.AsyncDownloadString(System.Uri(url))
   let bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)
   let st = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
   let person = js.ReadObject(st) :?> Person

   printfn "Name: %s, Phone number: %d" person.Name person.Phone }


let x = main "x"
let y = main "y"

[x;y] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore<unit[]>
```

Comment: Something seems incorrect here...  I'm getting this exception from it: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/home/frew/code/fsharp/{"name":"john","phone":12312312}".